# Unwanted escape sequences in shell mode

Tags: shell

Post title: **Unwanted escape sequences in shell mode <s>that are NOT due to colorizing-attempts</s>**  
(see update below)

Any idea what can cause (unwanted) escape sequences to continue showing up in the Emacs `shell` prompt (i.e., `M-x shell`) despite:

(i) removing all color-related sequences from prompt definitions in the appropriate config files and

(ii) including the following in my `init.el` file:

```
(autoload 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on "ansi-color" nil t)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

For example, this is what my shell prompt looks like (in Emacs)...

```
^[[J%
```

...but this is how  I've defined the prompt in my `.zshrc` file (I could be wrong but I suspect the issue is shell agnostic, i.e., I don't think it's specific to `zsh`).

```
PROMPT='%% '
```

Similarly, this is what my GHCi interpreter prompt (i.e., Haskell REPL) looks like:

```
^[[?1h^[=λ:
```

...when this is the definition I've included in the `ghci.conf` file:

```
:set prompt "λ: "
```

Running Emacs 24.4 on Lubuntu 14.04 with zsh as default shell.  (All zsh features are working correctly in Emacs; this seems like a cosmetic issue.)

**UPDATE: Solved** 
Shoddy attention to detail on my part; the following line in my `.zshrc` profile was responsible:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Comment: [There are more ANSI escape sequences than the ones that color your output](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php). You just don't get to see them in other terminal emulators since they actually interpret them while M-x shell prints them out if it can't deal with them correctly.

Comment: Consider posting your update as an answer and accepting it. (This will make sure that this question does not show up in the list of unanswered questions.)

Comment: okay, will do, thx (it says I have to wait two days before accepting my answer, so I'll do so at that time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it was shoddy attention to detail on my part; the following line in my .zshrc profile was responsible:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```