# weird characters in shell mode with zsh

Tags: shell, shell-mode, zsh

I recently switched to zsh (with *oh-my-zsh*) as my primary shell, but running the shell from emacs results in some strange (for lack of a better word) "residural" characters; however changing to bash removes these characters:

```
➜  ~  ^[[?2004h bash
 bash^[[?2004l
coffee@Lappy:~$
```

Is there any way for me to keep using zsh in emacs without it looking like absolute garbage?

Comment: `M-x ansi-term` is what you want.

Comment: This reminds me of [the question about Unwanted escape sequences in shell mode](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5522/2355).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The control sequences `^[[?2004h` and `^[[?2004l` turn [bracketed paste mode](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Bracketed-Paste-Mode) on and off.

Shell mode doesn't support bracketed paste mode (with these or any other control sequences), so zsh shouldn't try to turn it on. Shell mode correctly advertises that it doesn't support these control sequences by declaring `TERM=dumb`. It seems that zsh blindly assumes that the terminal either supports or ignores these two control sequences. That's a bug in zsh, which I can reproduce with zsh from git.

As a workaround, disable bracketed paste mode in your `.zshrc` if the terminal doesn't support escape sequences.

```
if [[ $TERM = dumb ]]; then
  unset zle_bracketed_paste
fi
```

Comment: Elegant and simple solution that did the trick, thanks!

Comment: This really helps me, thank you.

Comment: I am having `^[[31m^[[1m^[[31mdoo^[[0m^[[0m^[[0m` as red color output of the string, could it be also solved by `unset zle_bracketed_paste` ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like bad color encodings. Try using `ansi-color` like so http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Shell#More_colors or with `M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on`.

ps: yes it's possible, I use zsh !

Comment: No, `^[[?2004h`/`^[[?2004l` isn't related to colors. It's the control sequence to turn on/off [bracketed paste mode](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Bracketed-Paste-Mode).